# R: set leading row values to NA depending on condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Here is my example dataframe:

```
df <- tibble( id = c(rep('a', 5), rep('b', 6), rep('c', 6)),
  event = c("Visit 1", "Visit 2", 
                "Visit 3", "Visit 4", "Visit 5",  
                "Visit 1", "Visit 2", "Visit 3",
                NA, "Visit 4", "Visit 5",
                "Visit 1", NA, "visit 2", 
                "Visit 3","Visit 4", "Visit 5"),
             expected_output = c("Visit 1", "Visit 2", 
                                 "Visit 3", "Visit 4", "Visit 5",  
                                 "Visit 1", "Visit 2", "Visit 3",
                                 NA,  NA,  NA, "Visit 1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

I would like to create a new column where, grouped by `id`, whenever an `NA` occurs in the column `event` then all subsequnt rows should be set to `NA`. as can be seen in the `expected_output` column.

Here is my attempt, creating a new column `expected_output_b` using the `lead` function, however it doesn't work. Can anyone else help with this as unfortunately I can't think of another way to approach it.

```
df <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate( expected_output_b = if_else(is.na(event), all(lead(event)) == NA, event))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, new := ifelse(df[, cumsum(is.na(event)) > 0, by = .(id)]$V1, NA, event)]
#    id   event expected_output     new
# 1:  a Visit 1         Visit 1 Visit 1
# 2:  a Visit 2         Visit 2 Visit 2
# 3:  a Visit 3         Visit 3 Visit 3
# 4:  a Visit 4         Visit 4 Visit 4
# 5:  a Visit 5         Visit 5 Visit 5
# 6:  b Visit 1         Visit 1 Visit 1
# 7:  b Visit 2         Visit 2 Visit 2
# 8:  b Visit 3         Visit 3 Visit 3
# 9:  b    <NA>            <NA>    <NA>
#10:  b Visit 4            <NA>    <NA>
#11:  b Visit 5            <NA>    <NA>
#12:  c Visit 1         Visit 1 Visit 1
#13:  c    <NA>            <NA>    <NA>
#14:  c visit 2            <NA>    <NA>
#15:  c Visit 3            <NA>    <NA>
#16:  c Visit 4            <NA>    <NA>
#17:  c Visit 5            <NA>    <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` grouped by `id` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(result  = replace(event, row_number() > which(is.na(event))[1], NA)) %>%
  ungroup

#   id    event   result 
#   <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
# 1 a     Visit 1 Visit 1
# 2 a     Visit 2 Visit 2
# 3 a     Visit 3 Visit 3
# 4 a     Visit 4 Visit 4
# 5 a     Visit 5 Visit 5
# 6 b     Visit 1 Visit 1
# 7 b     Visit 2 Visit 2
# 8 b     Visit 3 Visit 3
# 9 b     NA      NA     
#10 b     Visit 4 NA     
#11 b     Visit 5 NA     
#12 c     Visit 1 Visit 1
#13 c     NA      NA     
#14 c     visit 2 NA     
#15 c     Visit 3 NA     
#16 c     Visit 4 NA     
#17 c     Visit 5 NA
```